# How to properly inject object-scene dependencies in unity with zenject

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

I have a scene object with a Fruit test script whose interfaces I want to add to dependencies. To do this, I use the standard Zenject Binding script. However, this doesn't work. Please tell me how can I solve the problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add your screenshots to the question itself as embedded images rather than links as links might break with time.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. When editing the question, I found only one way to add images, which I used.

Comment: It should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the container what to do with the depencencies. This is done with installers. There is a installing phase where you need to set the relation between the classes and the instances that need to be provided by the container. I recomend to read the documentation which is very good in this case.

For the case of `MonoDehaviour`s you need to check the [Scene bindings](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject#scene-bindings) section in the documentation.

```cs
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
}
    
public class GameInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public Foo foo;
    
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInstance(foo);
        Container.Bind<IInitializable>().To<GameRunner>().AsSingle();
    }
}
    
public class GameRunner : IInitializable
{
    readonly Foo _foo;

    public GameRunner(Foo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }
    
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

For your specific case:

```cs
public class Fruit: Monobehaviour. IInitializable, ITickable {
    public void Initialize() {

    }
    public void Tick() {

    }
}

public class GameInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public Fruit fruit;

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInstance(fruit);
        Container.Bind<IInitializable>().To<Fruit>().AsSingle();
        Container.Bind<ITickable>().To<Fruit>().AsSingle();
    }
}
```

Or you can also bind all the interfaces at once with:
`Container.BindInterfacesTo<Fruit>().AsSingle();`.

You need to add the `GameInstaller` in your `SceneContext` component for the installers to run along with the overridden `InstallBindings()` method.